# Extend x-limits using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to plot a histogram with an overlay (given by my_fun) using the following code.

```
dfr = data.frame(x)
ggplot(dfr,aes(x)) + geom_histogram(colour="darkblue", binwidth = 0.1, 
         aes(y =..density..), size=1, fill="blue", freq = TRUE)+
          stat_function(fun = my_fun, colour = "red")
```

The x-axis in ggplot is from 1 to 2 (which is the range of my data). However, I would like my plot to have an x-axis from 0 to 3, so that the overlay can be drawn over the range (0, 3).

I've tried adding `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 3))` but this does not work. Could you please provide me with some suggestions on changing the range? Thank You.

Comment: what is `my_fun` and can you provide the results of `dput(dfr)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing here since you provided only a little useful information in your question, but this works for me:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),freq=TRUE) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour="red") + 
    xlim(c(-4,4))
```

using `xlim` rather than `coord_cartesian`. But since you haven't provided any details on your data or function, I can't assure you that this will work in your case.

Comment: Thank You. This works. The function myfun was actually a density function

Comment: adding to Joran's answer, sometimes it makes sense to set an equal frame: `+ xlim(c( -max(abs(dat$x ) ), max(abs(dat$x ) ) ) )`